# Arrays.sort(ind, (l, r) -> nums[l] - nums[r]);

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

Can anybody explain to me how this piece of code works.

```
 Arrays.sort(ind, (l, r) -> nums[l] - nums[r]);
```

```
nums = [3,2,4]

ind = [0,1,2]
```

I debugged it and noticed that

```
l = 1
r = 0

then 

l = 2
r = 1

then 

l = 2
r = 0
```

and i get

```
ind = [1,0,2]
```

I am confused. Can anyone kindly explain how it worked.

Comment: Looks like it's sorting `int` on the basis of some sort of weight defined by `nums`.

Answer (score 1):

`ind` is an array of index values, initially index values from 0 to len-1.

The call to `sort()` will sort the index values by the value in `num` at the given index.

The result is that if you print `num[i]` for the values in `ind`, in the order present after the sort, the values will be in sorted order (ascending).

```java
for (int j = 0; j < ind.length; j++) {
    int i = ind[j];
    int num = nums[i];
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

```java
// Short version
for (int i : ind)
    System.out.println(nums[i]);
```

*Output*

```
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is using `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`.

This function is taking in parameter :

- The `Array` you want to sort
- A `Comparator`

`Comparator` is a interface that has just one method : `public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2)`. This method returns `x < 0`, `0` or `x > 0` if `obj1` is respectively `lower than`, `equal` or `greater than` `obj2`.

So, as `Comparator` has a unique method you can use a lambda, that's what is done here : `(l, r) -> nums[l] - nums[r]`.

This is a short version of "I am creating a new Comparator and here is what its unique method will do" :

- `(l, r)` : it takes l and r as arguments
- `nums[l] - nums[r]` it returns the result of that expression.

As you can see :

- if `nums[l]` > `nums[r]` the result is positive
- if `nums[l]` = `nums[r]` the result is 0
- if `nums[l]` < `nums[r]` the result is negative